# Difference between a normal object and a Class object in java

Tags: java

Recently I was learning annotations in java and came across Reflection API and a part of its code was:

```
Meta obj = new Meta();
//Get a Class object
CLass<?> c = obj.getClass();
```

The thing that I am not able to understand is that what is the difference between object `obj` and object `c` since both of them are just class objects.

Comment: `obj` is of type `Meta`, but `c` is of type `Class`.  The `Class` type is just another class, and instances of it just represent the different classes you have loaded.  `Class` instances have methods and data of the `Class` class, and `Meta` instances have methods and data of the `Meta` class.  `c` technically has a type parameter of `Meta`, but due to type erasure, that gets erased at runtime, so it is really just of type `Class`.

Answer (score 0):

You could treat `Class` object as `metadata of normal object`. Moreover, when you get `obj.getClass()` e.g. for different `Integer` objects, you'll get **the smae** `Class` object.